# Can`t connect to SQL server from Android

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server

I want to get connected to SQL server from an Android. I want to access the data from SQL server. But it is not getting connected. Please help me to solve this.

I have included **jtds-1.2.7.jar**

Here is my `MainActivity` (I mention where I got an error in program) :

```
try{
    String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

    conUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.15 :1433/Retail_MB;encrypt=fasle;user=sa;password=123;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
    uname = "sa";
    pass = "123";

    /////// On this statement it gives error...
    connect = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl,uname,pass);

    Statement statement=connect.createStatement();
    rs=statement.executeQuery(str);

    while(rs.next()){
    Log.w("Data:",rs.getString(0));
    }
    connect.close();

    } catch (Exception e){
    Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

It gives the **error on DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl,uname,pass);**

The error is an IOExeption:

```
socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

This is my **Manifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.alphahms"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.alphahms.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What is the problem? Android and SQL Server experts please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your Android Manifest.

It allows applications to open network sockets.

Comment: I was tried to add this but when I add this to my manifest App take some time to open and say ** App_name isnt responding Do you want to close it?** and in logcat it shows `12-30 10:27:35.160: I/dalvikvm(6630): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-30 10:27:35.211: I/dalvikvm(6630): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
` @Arnaud Christ

Comment: Sure sir, Kindly check my question again I update Manifest there. @Arnaud Christ

Comment: I am waiting for your reply mr. Arnaud Christ. @Arnaud Christ.

Answer (score 0):

The first `EACCES (Permission denied)` is because you didn't have the internet permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

After adding that you get ANR application not responding. It's because you block the UI thread for 5 seconds or more. You shouldn't do network requests on the UI thread but use a background thread for them. `AsyncTask` is probably the easiest way to offload operations to a backgrond thread. (Since your `targetSdkVersion` is 18 which is higher than 11, you should also get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` for doing network operations on the UI thread - I guess you have suppressed that exception in code you're not showing.)

Generally, doing JDBC database connections from a mobile client is a bad idea. JDBC protocols are designed for high-throughput low-latency networks for example in a data center. Mobile data networks are slow and unreliable to use JDBC efficiently. Instead, create a web service for your remote database operations and connect your mobile app to the web service.

Comment: Kindly check out my code I have added INTERNET permission before aplication. And you are right it shows ANR application not responding. How can i solve that? And **I have made my targetSdkVersion to 17** What else I Should do. Please help me to solve this or Please take my code in your adt and after you can solve paste code in anser. @laalto

Comment: @LalitSuryawanshi Best option is to throw away the idea of doing JDBC connections from an Android app. Second best option is to do it in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: So how to do task  AsyncTask @laalto